# Gerar string seguramente aleatória em NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, criptografia

Como, usando a linguagem Javascript na plataforma NodeJS, gerar uma string, preferencialmente com tamanho configurável, **aleatória o suficiente para ser usada em rotinas que lidam com criptografia** e que por questões de segurança **não podem ser** insuficientemente aleatória?

Caso proponha mais de uma solução, preferencialmente explicitar qual considera que é mais aleatória, possivelmente com **referências adicionais externas**. Soluções que envolvem mais de uma fonte de gerador de aleatoriedade também são bem vindas, em especial se acompanhadas de explicação de vantagens, a exemplo de reduzir problemas com um sistema operacional explicitamente alterado por uma NSA da vida para gerar menos caos na hora de produzir aleatoriedade.

Mesmo que duas pessoas proponham o mesmo código, caso uma destas explique melhor ou prove com exemplos reais a dispersão de valores, será considerado como melhor resposta. Não basta copiar e colar código, deverá dissertar porque é uma boa solução.

Soluções que acessam diretamente um recurso do sistema operacional, usando por exemplo `exec = require('child_process').exec; //(...)`  também são bem vindas.

Nota: favor não propor soluções que requeiram acessar um serviço externo via rede. A solução deve utilizar apenas a linguagem e o sistema operacional aonde está sendo executada. Acessar via HTTP qualquer serviço fora de uma rede interna não só impacta em performance como também é uma causa de falha de segurança.

Answer (score 3):

Use o módulo [Crypto](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html):

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
crypto.randomBytes(tamanho, function (erro, resultado /*buffer*/) {
  if (erro) {throw erro;}
  console.log('Uma string aleatória de %d bytes: %s', resultado .length, resultado);
});
```